# Unable to Navigate to a StackNavigator nested in a DrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I started with a drawer navigation to allow me to pick a category page as a starting point. From each category page I want to create a stack navigator so that it navigates with a stack without each page displayed in the drawer. I started by adding a StackNavigator to the "product" page, but was told to move it to the app page and used a nest navigator. So far, this is what I have...

App.js ( Nested Navigators )

```html
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        initialRouteName="LoL"
        drawerStyle={{
          backgroundColor: "#212121",
        }}
        drawerContentOptions={{
          activeTintColor: "orange",
          inactiveTintColor: "white",
        }}
      >
        <Drawer.Screen name="LoL" component={LoL} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="CSGO" component={CSGO} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="matchDetailsnav" component={matchDetailsNav} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const matchDetailsNav = () => {
  <Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name="MatchDetails" component={MatchDetails} />
</Stack.Navigator>
}
```

If we navigate to `LoL.js` we will see a list of cards to click on. I am using the following code to generate routes for each card.

```html
{matches.map((match, index) => {
          return (
            <View>
              <TouchableOpacity
                key={index}
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('matchDetailsNav', match)}
              >
                <Card
                  .. passing some props here..></Card>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
```

This is where I started to get the following error...

```
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {** .. obj of the props im passing .. not important to question *} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'MatchDetails?

If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.
```

This was happening before I added the stack navigator but I am not sure why. I am importing the MatchDetails page into the `App.js`, there is not naming typo in my code, and I cannot seem to find why it doesn't see my match details page. Why is it not picking up my page?

***EDIT:*** I just noticed that adding the nested navigator like I did in the example above put the name "matchDetailsNav" in my drawer nav as a clickable link, which is not what I want.

I simply want to gave a drawer nav and then have regular stack navigation for the pages/screens that link within the drawer nav. This way, clicking on a card living on a screen that is accesable from the Drawer Nav should use a stack nav ( allowing for the back button and sliding animation ).

I hope this edit clears up exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: Read the error message. It literally tells you what to do in a link.

Comment: I read the link provided https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator and I tried `this.props.navigate()` and it did not work.

Comment: @satya164 Here is what I am trying to do https://imgur.com/a/n6azrpn

Comment: Can you update your question with what you did after following the docs and what didn't work?